# how to make website available offline?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, offline-caching

today I just saw, that some websites ([example](https://qrsnapper.appspot.com/)) in google chrome for android show a notification, that the page is now available offline. I didn't find any information about that, how you can create your website that it's available after the first connection. I'm working on a manual and it would be a nice tweak if the user just needs to visit once and could use it offline then.
thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot to learn on this topic. And since what you asked is a broad topic I can only advise you to start from this.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: thank you for the link. I'll have a look at it. I guess, this will become a lot more important in the near future, when we're going away from native apps to web apps.